# Unconditional formatting universally applied in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

How do I change the [default](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/O6dioEx9g7g) color for anything which I type into Google Sheets?

When it's a URL it seems to go to one color, when not, another.  I'm not looking to delve into JavaScript.   I just want everything typed or pasted in, any text at all, to be a specific color.  Going [back](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/O6dioEx9g7g) to change the font is awkward.

I want unconditional, or every condition, formatting.  This is ***not*** a JavaScript question, nor is it how to set up conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't 100% automatic, but the [Table Styles Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-styles/miephfllckffagckloelhmnbefefbldl?utm_source=zapier.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=zapier) says it can apply formatting with one click. Does that help at all?